# How to add a logout button at the end of Navigation Drawer List

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer List in which I have put certain Items like profile,addmission etc.Each Item corresponds to a fragment.Now I dont want to put the logout button inside the list but I want to put it below the navigation drawer list.As it is just doing the work of logging out the user and No user interaction is required for my application.I want that user clicks on logout and He/she logs out.So I want to put the Logout button separetly below the list.
xml:

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/drawerLL1"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@color/list_background"

>
<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/drawerButton1"
   android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:height="200dp"
    />
```

```
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: So, put one there. The Drawer doesn't have to be a ListView, or RecyclerView, or whatever you have there. It can be, e.g., a vertical LinearLayout with a ListView on top and a Button below.

Comment: How to programatically connect them.Can you please provide me with example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ListView and Button in a LinearLayout and add this layout as the second child of the DrawerLayout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llDisplay">

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

     <ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

     <Button
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but it was not allowing me to set the width,height and text attribs of the button

Comment: since you are using a widget of support library all attributes are not visible in drop down menu.You try and add them anyway. They will work

Comment: giving error:you must supply layout width attribute

Comment: you need to add the gravity attribute in linear layout instead of listview

Comment: width of linearlayout should be greater than width of list.40<240